# shorten selector traverse backwards to one selector

Tags: jquery

Is it possible to shorten/reduce this to one selector?

```
var tr = input.parent('td').parent('tr');
```

And I dont want to use `closests`

Comment: `input.closest('tr')` - http://api.jquery.com/closest

Comment: I only want to get the tr if it has exact this path

Comment: Any reason why you do not want to use closest? That's exactly the one (and the only one?) you need.

Comment: because a table can be inside another table

Comment: Which is exactly why you *should* use `closest()`...

Comment: no.. I dont want to fetch the DOM element if it doesn't exatly have this path..if it is not a child to td I don't want to get the element

Comment: Then, no. There is no better way.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [parents()](https://api.jquery.com/parents/)

```
var tr = input.parents('tr:first');
```

But as *Rory* suggested *closest()* is what you looking for.

Comment: Note that this will return a collection of `tr` if you're in a nested table

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan tr:first can do  since OP do not want to use closest?

Comment: True, but then you may as well just use `closest()`